# Where does virtualenvwrapper's activate script live on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I installed python2 and virtualenvwrapper on my ubuntu machine in order to run a very old set of scripts I've saved for an obscure task.

I run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python2
cd ~/path/to/my/project
pip install virtualenvwrapper
source ~/.virtualenvs/ccs/bin/activate
```

Unfortunately, this gives me something like `bash: ~/.virtualenvs/ccs/bin/activate: No such file or directory`

I also try

```
source env/bin/activate
```

and again get a `No such file or directory` message.

Is there a different place where this script is installed on Ubuntu?

(I also tried `apt-get install virtualenvwrapper` with similar results.)

Comment: Virtualenvwrapper uses `workon <venv>` to activate an environment. For this to work you have add  something to your `.bashrc`. See the [docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251378/where-is-virtualenvwrapper-sh), it can be found in `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper`

you can add this to your `~/.bashrc` by doing:

```bash
$ echo 'source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper' >> ~/.bashrc
```

after *restarting your terminal (important!)*

```bash
$ bash
```

you can just call:

```bash
$ virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No luck. With both the `pip install virtualenvwrapper` version and the `apt-get install virtualenvwrapper` version, I do get any file in that location.

Comment: maybe the original post would have more information regarding this, sorry i couldnt be of more help